# Including files within a class?

Tags: php, oop, dependencies

I have my main class defined like so:

```
class Admin {

    private $theme_name;

    function __construct($theme_name) {
        $this->theme_name = $theme_name;
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init(){
        // load the framework files

    }


}
```

Instantiating this class will load all the individual module classes, and instantiate them.

My question is, should I include the necessary files within the init method, like so:

```
private function init(){
        // load the framework files
        require_once ( 'interface.php' );
        require_once ( 'uploader.php' );
        //etc ..

        $interface = new Interface(); //etc..

}
```

Or, should I include them above the class declaration like so:

```
require_once ( 'interface.php' );
require_once ( 'uploader.php' );
class Admin { //etc..
```

What is the best way to include dependencies within a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are good , but the seconde one is better ,it keeps code more beautiful.

I suggest to change your `init()` method to `static` ,because it's not a behaviour of admin and to avoid instantiating Admin Object every time you want to include those files.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, because all `Admin` instances require those additional files, it makes sense to pull those `require_once` statements to the top of your file.

Having said that, if you have an class autoloader you can clean up the file even more. You register a function with [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) that will be called when a required class is not loaded yet; the function will find and load the necessary source file.

Answer (score 0):

They're both the same. I would include them outside the class though, to maintain better code cleanliness, and technically you're calling the includes each time your call the function, but in this case it's an `init` so sounds like it might only get called once.

Answer (score 0):

Autoload! It comes at a bit of a price (there's a lot of string work to be done which will add to load) but if you only need it for a couple, it should do the job nicely

http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Answer (score 0):

You can use __autoload() function to pull in only the classes it needs to be called.

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name)
{
   $filename = "../class/".$class_name."php";
   if ( file_exists($filename) )
   {
       include_once $filename;
   }
}

?>
```